# C++ Game Started terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'

Tags: c++

Error is at the bottom with the output.

```
 Output:
```

Welcome to my Scramble Word Game!

a) Add Words into game database
b) Remove words
c) configure count down time
d) Start game
e) Select Game level
f) View score chart
g) Quit
Please enter an alphabet to select: d

Game Started
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
what():  vector::_M_range_check
apple orange melon lemondinosaur 
RUN FINISHED; Aborted; real time: 1s; user: 0ms; system: 0ms

below the code is my output , whats wrong with my code can anyone help me thanks , 
Any help will be appreciated!
Cheers!

Comment: Think we are missing part of your code, because what you are giving us as your "output" has some strings out that aren't in the code

Comment: `string jumble = levelList.at(rand()% wordList.size());` will the index always < levelList.size() ?

Comment: Did you try debugging into it? What line is it crashing on?

Comment: knowing the basics of std library is always a good start. The problem must happen when using the "at(...)" function, since it is the one that provides checked access (as opposed to "operator[]").

Answer (score 5):

```
levelList.at(rand()% wordList.size());
```

This is likely to be out of range some of the time, since `wordList` is likely to be larger than `levelList`.

Presumably, you meant

```
levelList.at(rand()% levelList.size());
                     ^^^^^^^^^
```

You are also not initialising the `level` variable declared in `startGame`, so it's likely that `levelList` will be completely empty. Presumably, you want to use the function argument to specify the level instead.

Comment: Wordlist and levellist is actually the same , just that levellist will compare the words and sort according to different level

Comment: @WilsonTurner: No, `levelList` is populated only with some of the words in `wordList`, depending on the value of `level`, so it will usually be smaller. Also, since you never initialise `level`, it's likely to be empty.

Comment: when my game menu is up , i already prompt user to input for level.

Comment: @WilsonTurner: Yes, and you pass that as an argument called `sl` to `startGame`. However, you don't use that argument, but instead declare a local variable called `level`, which you use without initialising.

Comment: so i should use sl instead of level?

Comment: @WilsonTurner: Yes. Or better still, rename it `level`, and remove the local variable.

Answer (score 2):

If you word file contains any words which are less than two characters, `levelList` will be shorter than `wordList`, so this line

```
levelList.at(rand()% wordList.size());
```

will cause the problem you state.

Answer (score 0):

You do not explicitly assign a value to your variable 'level' which is set to 0. Your switch statement does not cover this case, so your levelList is empty. You then try to access an entry in your zero-length level list which causes the out-of-range message.